# Trees & soap used to deter deer

Tags: trees, deer

If I use bars of soap to deter deer from destroying my trees, does the bar of soap in any way harm the trees? Whether I hang it from the tree, or place it on the ground around the trees? I tried using soap that had a strong odor, like Coast & Irish Spring. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you mean they are rubbing antlers on the bark , I have found wire fencing works well to protect the tree. I cut a length of fence that will wrap around very loosely , making a ring a few inches larger than the trunk.

Comment: I use hardware cloth (1/4" wire mesh) shaped into a ring, as blacksmith said, a few inches larger than the trunk; I use hardware cloth instead of wire fencing because I also want to keep voles from eating the bark under the snow. I make sure that the ring will sit below mulch/ground level by an inch or so, then tie it to a stake and use ground staples to secure it further. If you're in an area that gets a decent amount of snow, use 4 foot wide hardware cloth rather than the more-common 3 foot size. With this type of setup, you can leave the hardware cloth around the tree for several years,

Answer (score 0):

Best not placed on the ground, but hung from the tree you're trying to protect, or on a post nearby. Placing soap on the ground might mean other animals might be in danger from it, and as it dissolves in rain, the soapy water will enter the soil. Too much soap entering the soil won't be great for any plants growing in it. Some advice on using soap bars as a deterrent here https://homeguides.sfgate.com/use-soap-keep-deer-away-92916.html